# Why is gcc-multilib output incorrect for bitwise operation?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow

**bug.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 0x7fffffff;
    printf("%x\n", x);
    printf("%x\n", ~x);
    printf("%x\n", ~x + ~x);
    printf("%x\n", !(~x + ~x));
}
```

I compile using **gcc -m32 bug.c -o bug**
This outputs:

```
7fffffff
80000000
0
0
```

It should output

```
7fffffff
80000000
0
1
```

I am using gcc 9.3 and gcc-multilib on Ubuntu 20.04. I have also tested this with gcc8 and gcc10. The output was correct when I used clang. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Interestingly enough `printf("%x\n", !((unsigned)~x + ~x));` [prints 1](https://godbolt.org/z/qc3Enb). I guess `~x + ~x` is UB here because of integer overflow, but I'll defer that argument to the real language lawyers.

Comment: Technically passing an `int` argument to `printf` with a `%x` format specifier is also undefined behavior, as it expects `unsigned int`.

Comment: The [unoptimized assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/fxbrYr) is interesting.  I guess the idea is that in the absence of overflow, `~x + ~x == 0` if and only if `~x == 0` if and only if `x == -1`.  And if there were overflow then the behavior is undefined and thus that case needn't be handled.  So the compiler effectively converts `!(~x + ~x)` to `x == -1`, which is of course false.

Answer (score 4):

Enable all warnings and undefined behavior sanitizer with the `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fanalyzer -fsanitize=undefined` options and you'll see that gcc outputs this error

```
example.cpp:8:11: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483648 * 2 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

You can also specify more sanitizers like this `-fsanitize=signed-integer-overflow,leak,undefined,address`

See demo on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLp1IAHVAsLraewyaCnt5qdFY29kZOLpxuSiqhtAwEzMQE/samccqYqr7JqQThdo7OroopaRmBcZVF1iVRZbEAlIqoBsTIHADkUgDM1siGWADU4v06CgT4qAB0CBPY4gAMAIKra9YEo0bM1hAtm%2BIA7LLro5ej26MAHuP9ACKjK7cnVB%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%2BIV3yOphM4djZMYpI6kkpppIqQpFOU9SGm4soAzaXVOm6LhZXlRV42nDUelud1vXAkNRmAZBMNrV1RggXBCBIQ03FGPRKxLAKWiC39pBNBM2ggJAKyLEtyEoBKqxcYYRBrWs3EbVhm2IVt22nLtaF7fslSHEdx0nRdMDnYAF2nJc5PXTc1Q4ndkD3Xp2sPcN2pPM8LwwHqTVvcrHzoRgWAXd8BHrL8xEi/8HEA%2B0QLA%2BUoJguDIIQ89kNQ9C8Ew8CqGI2hSMwcjKKwGjUPohJfE0bRFI47QNJ4twxMSN6ft8T7mkUBjEgKKp9EyQQVNB/SIikqGFIhmptLSQGYhMvVzM4SyFSVFV2rshynJcjLRFGWI5hWOZOG83yiGIALEWCxLCIGSRwq1GQ5GijMLSdb1JDmCFhe9FZ%2Bn6RzQwhb0hHlSNSGjb0ITmbhvROWMAyl90Tndfp63xxMemTVNSHTc0s1zOKQA6Ah3D3ZLywLFmYg4/B6cEJ9ptfZ1SAAd3PdwJtl3GbIJ%2BUBhp33CAQO5HOc7hXPc8mqckHnzatm27YIB3UpLEB61QvyXc9l9Zt4f3mED%2B9M3DayDdIOy2dGKOCBjon49GUngHJzhKeptOZRx%2BXo36F0IT1gMAxWCETm4ThJB9E4ZfruzjbcM3B8dEB/TmE4IViXWvW4MX%2Bhn4P%2BjxjtV9NmKcdT0PDYHi11wK57uCAA%3D%3D%3D). Notice that Clang also reports UB:

```
example.cpp:8:23: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483648 + -2147483648 cannot be represented in type 'int'
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior example.cpp:8:23 in 
example.cpp:9:25: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483648 + -2147483648 cannot be represented in type 'int'
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior example.cpp:9:25 in
```

Answer (score 1):

That's signed integer overflow which is technically UB, although I'm surprised somebody managed to observe it with bitbashing. Usually that's weird loop bounds behaviors. If you want weird bit operations to work, use unsigned int, which is specified to wrap.